# Ansible / vmware_guest_network does not connect nic after addition

Tags: ansible, vmware, ansible-facts, vmware-workstation

We have a requirement to add a new NIC to several VMs on Vmware.
To do this we are using **ansible 2.9.3** and **Python Version =  2.7.5**

Here is the main playbook for the addition:

```
---
-
  become: false
  gather_facts: false
  hosts: srvlist
  tasks:
    -
      vmware_guest_network:
        hostname: "{{ vcenter_hostname }}"
        password: "{{ vcenter_password }}"
        username: "{{ vcenter_username }}"
        validate_certs: false
        cluster: "{{ vm_cluster }}"
        datacenter: "{{ vm_datacenter }}"
        gather_network_info: false
        name: "{{ vm_name }}"
        networks:
          -
            device_type: vmxnet3
            dvswitch_name: SWITCH1
            name: "TESTPORTGROUP|TEST_APP"
            start_connected: true
            state: new
            connected: true
      delegate_to: localhost
  vars:
    vcenter_hostname: "any.sample.ip"
    vcenter_password: mypassword
    vcenter_username: administrator
    vm_name: myNewDuplicatedVM
    vm_cluster: ANY_CLUSTER_NAME
    vm_datacenter: ANY_DATACENTER_NAME
```

Playbook is partially working, the issue from here is that the new NIC is not connected after the creation and we can see the properties correctly set up:

```
start_connected: true
state: new
connected: true
```

Also we can see on that the `name` variable inside `networks` uses the label/name for the appropriated portgroup: `name: "TESTPORTGROUP|TEST_APP"`

Remember this will be a new NIC; that means we have one already working.
Now, when I fetch for details using `vmware_guest_network` only to gather details from the VM it shows me a different name than expected:

```
ok: [vcenter_ip] => {
    "vminfo": {
        "changed": false,
        "failed": false,
        "network_data": {
            "0": {
                "allow_guest_ctl": true,
                "connected": true,
                "device_type": "VMXNET3",
                "label": "Network adapter 1",
                "mac_addr": "00:50:56:89:78:42",
                "name": "DVSwitch: d9 27 09 50 0e ty b7 e2-91 b0 52 1d 6b 79 26 45",
                "start_connected": true,
                "unit_number": 7,
                "wake_onlan": true
            },
            "1": {
                "allow_guest_ctl": true,
                "connected": false,
                "device_type": "VMXNET3",
                "label": "Network adapter 2",
                "mac_addr": "00:50:56:89:a1:65",
                "name": "TESTPORTGROUP|TEST_APP",
                "start_connected": true,
                "unit_number": 8,
                "wake_onlan": true
            }
        }
    }
```

The first one is the already present NIC and the second one is new one and is not connected as you can see.
I don't know why is not connected and either why the name its different.
I uderstand that nic stays in a disconnected state when there is an error in the customization stage but there is no errors show in vmlogs or on ansible.

I also tried using the entire, lets say, low level switch name but, as I expected, ansible fails and says that portgroup doesn't exist.

It may be a bug or I'm actually missing some configuration there.

Answer (score 2):

Are you using vmware-workstation or vsphere for hosts your VMs?
If you are using vsphere/vcenter, an easy way is use powerCLI to manage all vms with vsphere API. Just for add a new network card you use New-NetworkAdapter cmdlet, you can configure vs/vds, vlan, network card type, etc. Make you to take an snapshot before apply any change.

```
new-networkadapter -vm <vmname> -NetworkName "<Port group name>" -Type "VMXNET3" -startconnected
```

Answer (score 2):

I had this same issue and found that the issue for me was that perl was not installed on the template/VM. Recommend installing perl on the template being used and trying again. You may find some clues in the open-vm-tools logs.

Answer (score 2):

You could add the following powershell workaround in ansible. It is also based on PowerCli. PowerCli is for free and very easy to use. The same to powershell (pwsh) which is also needed.

```yaml
- name: activate Network of vm with PowerCli
  shell: |
    Connect-VIServer -Server $env:vcenter -Protocol https -force -User $env:vcuser -Password $env:vcpass
    Get-NetworkAdapter -VM $env:vm | Set-NetworkAdapter -Connected:$true -StartConnected:$true -confirm:$false
  args:
    executable: /usr/bin/pwsh
  environment:
    vcenter: "{{ vsphere_host }}"
    vcuser: "{{ vsphere_username }}"
    vcpass: "{{ vsphere_pw }}"
    vm: "{{ vm_name }}"
```

Explanation:

- `Connect-VIServer -Server ...` connects to the vcenter
- `Get-NetworkAdapter -VM $env:vm | Set-NetworkAdapter -Connected:$true -StartConnected:$true -confirm:$false` gets the networkadapter and then it sets both properties (connect and connect_on_start).